# Why does unittest.mock.patch work with testfixtures?

Tags: python-3.x, testing, mocking

Why doesn't accessing `unittest.mock.patch` throw an attribute error when I import testfixtures in the below code?

I myself suspect that it is because testfixtures might be importing `unittest.mock` somewhere internally however, is there any way I could change this behavior if I want unittest.mock to always be imported explicitly and get an AttributeError otherwise?

```py
import unittest
import sys
import os

import testfixtures

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    @unittest.mock.patch('sys.version_info', (2,7,0))
    def test_version(self):
        assert(sys.version_info < (3,0,0))
```

Accessing `unitest.mock` without importing it should throw an `AttributeError` but that's not the case when testfixtures is imported.

Comment: If it hasn't been imported *anywhere* (e.g. if the testfixtures import is later removed and nothing is added), you *will* get an AttributeError. What is your specific concern around when that happens?

Comment: This behavior is bad because if some imports depend on testfixtures internally, it's easy to forget to import `unittest.mock` and later on removing testfixtures would break the tests. I want to know if there's a way to avoid that?

Comment: And then, later on, *if that happened*, you could put the extra import in. It's not clear to me why that would be such a big problem.